# Python Linear regression using QR decomposition (correlated features)

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, linear-regression, qr-decomposition

I need to apply a Python linear regression on a dataset in which some features are correlated.

Scikit's linear regression uses the singular value decomposition in order to minimize the squared error. However, this method doesn't take into account the correlation between variables. R uses the QR decomposition, which is a technique for decorrelating covariates with the 'lm' method. The coefficients of the correlated variables are returned as NaN values, which is convenient for what I want to do.

I want to know if there is a built-in method to replicate these results in Python. If not, how can it be done ?

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ ., data = dataset)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-5.891e-17 -6.610e-18 -1.280e-18  3.280e-18  7.294e-16 

Coefficients: (106 not defined because of singularities)
              Estimate Std. Error    t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -6.000e-03  2.291e-18 -2.619e+15   <2e-16 ***
V1                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
V2                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
V3           1.000e+00  4.423e-17  2.261e+16   <2e-16 ***
V4                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
V5                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
V6           2.130e-16  3.128e-16  6.810e-01    0.496    
V7                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
V8                  NA         NA         NA       NA    
V9           9.876e-17  6.708e-16  1.470e-01    0.883    
V10                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V11                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V12                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V13                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V14                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V15         -4.318e-16  1.452e-15 -2.970e-01    0.766    
V16                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V17                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V18         -1.699e-15  2.550e-15 -6.660e-01    0.506    
V19                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V20                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V21                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V22                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V23                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V24          6.521e-16  2.441e-15  2.670e-01    0.789    
V25                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V26                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V27          2.411e-15  6.448e-15  3.740e-01    0.709    
V28                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V29                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V30                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V31                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V32                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V33                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V34                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V35                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V36                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V37                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V38                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V39                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V40                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V41                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V42          5.873e-16  2.896e-15  2.030e-01    0.839    
V43                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V44                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V45          3.060e-15  4.833e-15  6.330e-01    0.527    
V46                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V47                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V48                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V49                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V50                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V51          2.714e-15  3.917e-15  6.930e-01    0.489    
V52                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V53                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V54         -1.438e-14  1.023e-14 -1.406e+00    0.160    
V55                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V56                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V57                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V58                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V59                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V60                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V61                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V62                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V63                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V64                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V65                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V66                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V67                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V68                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V69         -3.462e-15  4.663e-15 -7.420e-01    0.458    
V70                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V71                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V72          2.390e-15  9.911e-15  2.410e-01    0.810    
V73                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V74                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V75                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V76                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V77                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V78          1.894e-15  9.962e-15  1.900e-01    0.849    
V79                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V80                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V81          2.810e-14  2.967e-14  9.470e-01    0.344    
V82                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V83                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V84                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V85                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V86                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V87                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V88                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V89                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V90                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V91                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V92                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V93                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V94                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V95                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V96                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V97                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V98                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V99                 NA         NA         NA       NA    
V100                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V101                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V102                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V103                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V104                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V105                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V106                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V107                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V108                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V109                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V110                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V111                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V112                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V113                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V114                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V115                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V116                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V117                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V118                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V119                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V120                NA         NA         NA       NA    
V121                NA         NA         NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 3.439e-17 on 984 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:      1 
F-statistic: 8.757e+32 on 15 and 984 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

You can see here the significant coefficients :

```
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y_EC
           Df Sum Sq Mean Sq    F value  Pr(>F)    
V3          1 15.536  15.536 1.3136e+34 < 2e-16 ***
V6          1  0.000   0.000 1.1225e+00 0.28965    
V9          1  0.000   0.000 4.2900e-01 0.51265    
V15         1  0.000   0.000 2.3800e-02 0.87741    
V18         1  0.000   0.000 5.7980e-01 0.44655    
V24         1  0.000   0.000 2.2500e-02 0.88070    
V27         1  0.000   0.000 1.3820e-01 0.71017    
V42         1  0.000   0.000 4.0400e-02 0.84074    
V45         1  0.000   0.000 1.3070e-01 0.71783    
V51         1  0.000   0.000 1.9925e+00 0.15840    
V54         1  0.000   0.000 3.9217e+00 0.04795 *  
V69         1  0.000   0.000 5.6850e-01 0.45104    
V72         1  0.000   0.000 8.2600e-02 0.77386    
V78         1  0.000   0.000 8.8000e-02 0.76684    
V81         1  0.000   0.000 8.9710e-01 0.34378    
Residuals 984  0.000   0.000                       
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: I am not sure what I am looking at now (R or Python), but you can mimic R code with statsmodels. You can use PCA to remove correlation in your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this -quote **Compute QR decomposition of a matrix**
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr.html

Comment: I am mainly looking for a built-in regression method that uses QR decomposition, not the decomposition itself